# Is my XML output supposed to be like this?

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<staffs>
    <records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="employee">
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Danial</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <TFN>1231231</TFN>
        <contact>12314123</contact>
        <jobType>WAITER</jobType>
        <wage>12.0</wage>
    </records>
    <records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="employee">
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Andrew</name>
        <age>21</age>
        <TFN>1231254</TFN>
        <contact>123677</contact>
        <jobType>ADMIN</jobType>
        <wage>18.0</wage>
    </records>
    <records xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="employee">
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Jenny</name>
        <age>19</age>
        <TFN>1231432</TFN>
        <contact>1239873</contact>
        <jobType>WAITRESS</jobType>
        <wage>15.0</wage>
    </records>
    <employees>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Danial</name>
        <age>20</age>
        <TFN>1231231</TFN>
        <contact>12314123</contact>
        <jobType>WAITER</jobType>
        <wage>12.0</wage>
    </employees>
    <employees>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Andrew</name>
        <age>21</age>
        <TFN>1231254</TFN>
        <contact>123677</contact>
        <jobType>ADMIN</jobType>
        <wage>18.0</wage>
    </employees>
    <employees>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>Jenny</name>
        <age>19</age>
        <TFN>1231432</TFN>
        <contact>1239873</contact>
        <jobType>WAITRESS</jobType>
        <wage>15.0</wage>
    </employees>
</staffs>
```

anyways after using jaxb my output is the above.
is this normal?? why is it repeating the inputs?
Records holds the LinkedList and Employees extends Records

if there's away to prevent this would be keen to hear

```html
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "staffs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employees extends Records
{
  @XmlElement(type = Employee.class)
 public LinkedList<Record> getEmployees()
 {
  return super.getRecords();
 }
}


//////////////////////Employee class/////////////////
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
@XmlRootElement(name = "staff")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Employee extends Record
{
}
```

Comment: You are probably having a List of duplicate objects - that why you get them repeatedly - show us the code how you generate it and we might be able to find a solution.

Comment: @Alexander 
thats basically it.
i don't think i repeated a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ist because you have to getters that actually return the same list:

- Record.getRecords() and
- Employee.getEmployees().

see

```
public LinkedList<Record> getEmployees()
{
    return super.getRecords();
}
```

That's why you have this two almost identical Lists. Do you really need this duplicate getter? If not, just remove it and the output will be without the duplicates.

Comment: if i were to remove my getter in Employees class how would i reference to the list?
to i just set the element at the parent class?

Comment: yes, you can call `getRecords()` and `setRecords(List)` if they are public - no matter which class or subclass defines it. Guess why you can call `toString()` on any Object.

Comment: i got what you meant and got it fixed